# python practice for cli script with __main__

Tags: python

I have several cli python scripts and they are not targeted to be imported.
So, I put this code on top :

```
if __name__!='__main__':
  import sys
  sys.exit(0)
```

Is it a bad practice or good one ?
Main goal is to prevent to put all code into functions and put at the bottom

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    mybig_main_run()
```

Comment: Why would you actively prevent people from importing your module? _"Main goal is to prevent to put all code into functions"_ How is that related to imports? I don't see the connection.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Because it's a standalone script that doesn't make sense to be used as a module.

Comment: However, you really _should_ be wrapping your code up into functions. Not only is it neater, it's actually a little more efficient to not have all your names living in the global namespace.

Comment: this script does not make sense to be used as module, no need to import...

Answer (score 2):

I would say it is a bad practice.

There is no reason for doing that.

<strike>And it breaks an interactive console such as bpython, because `__name__` is `"__console__"`.</strike> (this has been [fixed in v0.18](https://github.com/bpython/bpython/commit/f189da1789211d267ee8d9ac345dcb3fa90cd338))

What usually is done is the opposite: avoid some global code being run when the module is imported, by checking `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

I don't see a reason why some other script **must not** import the functions of your script, but if you really want to enforce that, define your functions under the if block:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    def func1():
        pass

    def func2():
        pass

    # put main script code here
    # e.g.:
    func1()
    func2()
```

and a script that will try to import your script as a module will just get an empty module, instead of an unexpected `sys.exit()`.

Comment: so,  I need to indent all my code with 2 spaces after __name__ ?

Comment: @Tensor essentially, yes. You want to put all your code under the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.